# What is considered `sys` time in bash time util?

Tags: c, linux, bash, time, profiling

I've been profiling my linux app and in my single threaded build I noticed real/user/sys being 1900/1250/140. If I add up user and sys its 1390 which is far from 1900. 1900-is 510 which is a LARGE percentage.

What's considered as part of `sys`? I thought it was all system calls. After measuring some more it appears calling `write` takes up 500ms which is much larger than what sys is reporting and seems to be almost the entire missing time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this comment should be a question but what can I do while the OS is stalling for 500ms? I was thinking maybe creating a thread only to write might be a good idea? Or maybe I can mess with io_uring but I don't know if that's going to be more overhead than a thread if I only execute for about a second. I never tried nonblocking, if its a pipe with a child processes on the other end reading, can it be nonblocking or set up in a way with a large buffer so I don't get blocked as long?

Comment: Real includes time when your process is not running at all, because of timesharing.

Comment: It also doesn't include time when you're blocked waiting for a slow device like a terminal or network.

Comment: Looks like writing to file is fast and I was accidentally writing to the process. Is there a way I can have a larger pipe?

Comment: I think [ipe buffer size is configured when compiling the kernel, I don't think it can be modified dynamically.

Comment: time is a builtin in bash. It's probably using wait3(2) to get the information it gives you.